# Can you manage a CDK project with poetry?

Tags: python, aws-cdk, python-poetry

Trying CDK for the first time. While it is possible to use poetry for the function dependencies, I am looking for a way to also manage the CDK project itself using poetry.

Following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-python.html
the recommendation to set up a project contains these step:

```
cdk init app --language python
source .venv/bin/activate 
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to `poetry run cdk init app --language python` instead but `cdk init` requires an empty directory to begin with.

Is there a best practice to put the cdk project entirely under poetry? Otherwise using Typescript for the project and Python for the functions would be my next best option.

Comment: Sure, you don't have to use `cdk init` at all. Just create your python CDK files and do a `poetry init` to configure the environment.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it can be done. I do it for every Python CDK project I develop. As @gshpychka said, you can create the project yourself. You can also let `cdk init` do its thing and then delete `requirements.txt` and replace it with `pyproject.toml`. The `README.md` file might also need an update.

This part is not required, but I like updating `cdk.json` as well so Poetry is executed automatically for me. Replace:

```
{
  "app": "python app.py",
```

With:

```
{
  "app": "poetry run python app.py",
```

That way every time you run `cdk synth`, `cdk deploy` or any other command, it will automatically use Poetry for you.

Finally, you can use [projen](https://projen.io/) to generate the whole thing for you with Poetry. It is quite opiniated but does include a lot of useful features like scheduled GitHub Actions to update dependencies automatically, mergify, etc.

```
npx projen new awscdk-app-py --poetry
```